# Привлечение людей в чат

Tags: предложение, чат

Долго ходить вокруг да около не буду.

В [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) <s>надоели одни и те же рожи</s> довольно малое количество людей. В основном постоянные старенькие участники.

<s>Не только лишь все</s> Очень мало кто знает, что тут вообще есть чаты. Потому что ссылка на комнаты спряталась, как шпион, где-то внизу, среди множества ненужной информации.
Однако было бы неплохо если б людей поприбавилось.

Во-первых, новые лица.

Во-вторых, множество представителей различных направлений в IT могли бы иногда обмениваться информацией и что-то, возможно, узнать новое в беседах (когда беседа заходит по IT).

В-третьих, по-мелочи что-то спросить у власти (ибо не всякий и про мету знает) или у <s>местной фауны</s> уже обжившихся о правилах или мелких деталях в SO.

В-четвертых, (косвенной пункт) будут знать, что бывают тут не только монстры с синдромом вахтёра, но и адекватные разумные люди.

В-пятых, впишите свой вариант))

---

В связи с этим **есть некое предложение**:

к примеру каждый последний день месяца брать топ 100-150 активных участников ruSO (топ за месяц) и маякнуть о том, что есть тут не только вопросы, но и чат: общий, английский и прочие. Всем вэлком! Добро пожаловать <s>на голодные игры</s> к нам.

Глядишь, подтянется народ.

---

Небольшой спойлер с трудностями)

> Проблема только лишь одна и её надо кому-то решить: как именно этот "зазыв" осуществлять %)
>  Т.е. вручную через чат - накладно, вручную рассылкой через ПМ - вряд ли модераторы согласятся)) 
>  Еще надо где-то хранить значение, что уведомление было отослано и не отсылать уведомление, если как минимум 2 раза уже оно высылалось (А то @VladD не обрадуется каждый месяц получать уведомления %))

Comment: Не надо вообще никаких уведомлений тем, кто уже хотя бы раз был в чате.

Comment: Хотите лайфхак? Добавьте прямую ссылку в чат в вопрос и попробуйте попасть в "обсуждаемое на Мете" :D

Comment: @alexolut ну это дополнительное сложное условие имхо. Проще просто выбирать лучших в месяц и контролировать чтоб не больше N-раз им приходило сообщение

Comment: @D-side можно ещё добавить метку [meta-tag:важное].

Comment: ой какой сомнительный четвертый пункт

Comment: @Grundy, будут знать, что вахтеры тут настолько организованы и сильны, что у них даже есть специальный чат )

Comment: @Nofate, в который, очевидно, они никого не пустят :-)

Comment: Лично мне кажется что рассылка - метод не очень. Но вот над тем чтобы предлагать последовать в чат в причине закрытия с оффтопиком - я бы подумал. Те кто хотят "поболтать за it" будут знать что есть для этого специальное место.

Comment: @Grundy не пугай мне тут народ %)

Comment: Я бы такое "предложение" воспринял как спам. У каждого свои цели для участия, у каждого свои рамки этого участия. "Давайте все в чат!!!" --- нет, спасибо. Плюс, если брать сотню топовых участников, мне так кажется, что процент тех, кто _не знает_ о чате, среди них и так будет мизерный. А вот процент неучаствующих будет приличный, что, на мой вкус, вполне нормально.

Comment: @РоманХимов цели у каждого свои, поэтому это не принудительное мероприятие, а лишь подсказка о еще одной функции на сайте, которой кто хочет - может присоединяться, а может игнорировать, дело каждого.......... `если брать сотню топовых - процент тех, кто не знает о чате, среди них и так будет мизерный` -  вы путаете топ всех участников и топ недели/месяца. Бывает что это практически разные топы. Плюс минус. Причем даже кто в топе всех не все знают о чате.

Comment: Помнится, кого-то недавно забанили года на полтора за флуд в чате. Разбаньте его - станет весело (зловещий смех).

Comment: Думаю, нужно ссылку на чат сделать хорошо видимой, поместить в самом верху.

Comment: В основном народ заходит только лишь чтобы задать вопрос при необходимости и получить ответ. Заядлые же участники, которые тут как на работе сидят итак знают о чате - те самые "одни и те же рожи". Была бы интересная тема для общения в чате, возможно, подтянулось бы и больше народу.

Comment: @HamSter каждый может быть инициатором интересной темы ;-)