# Мы предпочитаем вопросы, на которые можно дать конкретные ответы, а не те, которые порождают дискуссию

Tags: обсуждение, тематика, правила

А если я хочу именно дискуссию? К примеру, я знаю 10 способов как решить свою задачу А под платформой Б при решении общей задачи В, но не знаю, какой из них наиболее оптимальный. Оптимальность, само собой, зависит от множества факторов, что порождает дискуссию - искомые знания.

Пример хорошей дискуссии: [Словарь на C++ как (Dictionary) на C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/189730/) - меня тут привлекает сравнение кода на куче разных языках и постоянные твики кода с желанием выжать еще пару процентов производительности, возможно жертвуя гигабайтами памяти и страницами кода.

Плашка же

> Мы предпочитаем вопросы, на которые можно дать конкретные ответы, а не
>   те, которые порождают дискуссию.

меня демотивирует. Что мне делать?

Comment: Идти в чат. Тут столько тематических чатов стонут от нехватки людей... [c++/c](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26298/c-c), [c#](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--), [f#](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f) и т.д. И вообще [больная тема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3983/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82)

Comment: @AK, а не тематический стонет от переизбытка тематики :)

Comment: в вашем "примере хорошей дискуссии" - один хороший полноценный ответ, и три ответа-комментария к этому ответу, которые вообще тяжело увязать с первоначальным вопросом.

Comment: У меня уже есть "знакомый Вася", которого я могу донимать вопросами вида "как лучше". Мне нужно место, куда можно будет запулить очередной сниппет и его увидят все, возможно кто-то еще сможет сделать лучше.

Comment: @bukkojot такие вопросы - онтопик, в рамках метки [tag:инспекция-кода]

Comment: Посмотрел чаты - что-то полумертвенькое и ненужное. По крайней мере по сишке.

Comment: @PashaPash, но ведь данный тег не только содержит в себе массу критериев, достаточную для просторного суждения модераторов о уместности его, равно как и "порождает дискуссии". Как же быть? Алсо, я не очень хорошо пока ориентируюсь на ресурсе, тут есть чат с вами лично?

Comment: @bukkojot личного чата нет. на плашке написано "Мы предпочитаем вопросы". там не написано "а все остальные вопросы мы удалим!". не совсем понимаю, что вы предлагаете поменять :)

Comment: Это развязывает руки модератору. Лично я воспринимаю это как "иди отсюда, у нас тут только индусы с невыполненой домашкой, один вопрос - один ответ, а если головой думать - это не сюда". Не только "мы удалим", но и забаним". Такова политика модерирования на многих ресурсах. Лично я всегда считал, что дискуссия - первейшее, что может быть для поиска знаний. Впрочем, допускаю, что это лично мое восприятие, испорченное модераторами-идиотами на других ресурсах.

Comment: @bukkojot вы не совсем верно понимаете роль модератора на ruSO. Модераторы вообще редко занимаются закрытием и удалением вопросов, за исключением дикого оффтопика. Сайт в основном модерируется обычными участниками с достаточно высокой репутацией. Если ваш вопрос по оптимизации окажется хорошим, конструктивным, и не приведет к холивару - никто его не тронет.

Comment: Тогда я предлагаю изменить формулировку плашки. Многие, пытаясь все русифицировать, просто недопускают слов "оффтопик" или "холивар", даже не смотря на то, что эти слова устоялись, такие люди переводят как "дискуссии", чем вводят меня в заблуждение. Это как русифицированный фотошоп 10-летней давности - можно долго ломать голову над тем, что же имеется в виду, а потом взять оригинал и разобраться за минуты.

Comment: @bukkojot, вы нашли хороший пример вопроса и ответов на него, только не сделали поправку на прошедшие с того момента 4 года, за которые многое тут изменилось. Да, сейчас подобные дискуссии в принципе возможны в чатах (если сумеете заинтересовать их постояльцев)

Comment: @avp, во-первых, я в данном сообществе недавно, потому понятия не имею, что тут было раньше и что сейчас, это все прошло мимо меня. Во-вторых, в интернете существует миллион чатов, в том числе некоторыми управляю я сам. В общем, может быть это выбор сообщества, не мне его упрекать, но для меня такое сообщество ценности не представляет. Я предпочту  что-нибудь другое. Что-то такое, где есть срачи за истину и кто-то готов выдрачивать код до последнего байтика, а сообщество кастратов найти можно где угодно.

Comment: @avp, к слову, я только из-за той дискуссии тут и зарегался. Оказывается, я опоздал.

Comment: @bukkojot , если Вам не нравится формат сообщества, это ещё не причина оскорблять его участников. Желаю Вам успехов в поисках места "где есть срачи за истину".

Comment: Я никого не оскорблял. А желающий оскорбиться всегда найдет где. Как говорится, свинья грязи найдет.

Answer (score 12):

### Дискуссия дискуссии рознь.

Здесь намеренно отвергается формат *форума*.

У нас тут формат *вопросов и ответов*, и всё остальное лишь поддержка для него. И порой дискуссии оказываются необходимы, правда. И если дискуссия приводит к уточнению вопроса или улучшению ответа, то она для формата "вопрос-ответ" полезна и сообщество вряд ли её осудит. Но *полезная часть дискуссии, выводы, должна осесть в сообщениях (вопросах и ответах то бишь),* а не оставаться в комментариях.

Можно рассматривать этот процесс как "дистилляцию выводов из дискуссий". Размазанное на три страницы на форуме (разбавленное водой, оформлением между сообщений, спорами, противоречиями) зачастую можно изложить в паре абзацев. Спасайте самое ценное из дискуссий, а остальное за борт.

Комментарии (почти единственное средство ведения здесь дискуссий) стоит воспринимать как нечто дополнительное, что большинство читателей пропустит. Считайте что они якобы под труднодоступным спойлером. Или, лучше, что они в любой момент могут исчезнуть.

На StackOverflow не любят **дискуссии ради дискуссий**, и, как следствие, не любят вопросы, которые *в первую очередь порождают дискуссии*, а ответов не порождают вовсе ли порождают совершенно несодержательные и/или бесполезные. Так, чисто дискуссионный вопрос в долгосрочной перспективе может обзавестись парочкой удалённых никому не нужных ответов и здоровенной веткой комментариев, которая за неимением ответов не представляет ценности на ресурсе. Такой вопрос получается для сайта бесполезен, но усилия на него получаются потрачены. Получается, впустую. Поэтому существование таких вопросов и вклад в них пресекаются заранее.

Скажем, если в вопросе "слишком много переменных" (факторов для рассмотрения, пустых мест, и т. п.), чтобы устраивать в ответе полный перебор возможных вариантов, некоторые отвечающие описывают один или несколько. И ой, не попадают в проблему, которую решает автор. И в этом виноваты все: автор (что недостаточно точно сформулировал вопрос), отвечающий (что бросился на амбразуру, не до конца поняв ситуацию) и сообщество (что вовремя не предотвратило микротрагедию закрытием вопроса).

---

Вопрос, который вы приводите в пример, очень старый, времён ХэшКода ещё. Сейчас он, не имея ответов, скорее всего был бы закрыт по вышеописанной причине как "слишком общий". А вовсе не из-за дискуссий, которые под ним образовались, нет.

Это такой способ донести до автора тот факт, что есть определённый порог объёма ответов, выше которого рассчитывать на ответы уже неразумно. Что есть смысл скорее сузить вопрос, чем ждать ответ, т. к. его можно долго прождать.

Авторам вопросов не стоит рассчитывать на то, что на их вопросы дадут большие ответы. Большие ответы не запрещены, просто они нетипичны для ресурса и не стоит ждать таких изначально.

---

И да, рассуждения об абстрактной "оптимальности" как правило бесполезны примерно по той же причине, по которой бесполезны синтетические тесты: они актуальны для узкого круга задач, причём часто не пересекающегося с реальными задачами.

Однако если внести в вопрос об оптимальности достаточно конкретики, чтобы можно было предложить конкретное решение... почему бы и нет. Если, конечно, кто-то за решение вообще возьмётся.

---

В комментариях вы предложили изменить формулировку плашки. Это можно. Теперь, когда вы точно знаете о недостатках в формулировке плашки, вы можете подготовить вопрос, в котором можно описать исправляемые проблемы и предложить новые варианты (ответами). Как-то вот так у нас демократия работает.

Comment: Я вас угадал по стилю изложения.

Answer (score 6):

Оптимальность как таковая не имеет смысла. В реальных задачах всегда есть некие условия оптимизации. Как-то так:

- Выгода от получения результатов считается по формуле `C - kT`, где C – выгода от моментального результата, T – время вычисления, а k – некий положительный коэффициент.

  Да, через некоторое время результаты могут быть никому не нужны. В масштабе продукта — опоздавший за конкуренцией стартап тоже никому не нужен.
- Время вычисления зависит от вложенного труда как-нибудь логарифмически: `T = T0 - ln(L)`. Чем дальше — тем тяжелее.
- Час работы 1 ядра CPU стоит, например, $0.01
- Час работы 1 GB RAM стоит $0.02
- Час работы специалиста по оптимизации кода стоит $100.

Если вы можете сформулировать четкие и однозначные факторы, **получится отличный вопрос**. В ином случае вы наверняка будете оптимизировать только оплату труда специалиста по оптимизации кода. А это тема холиварная и формату сайта она не соответствует. :)

Comment: Час работы специалиста по оптимизации кода - бесценно

Comment: @PashaPash а для остального есть StackOverflow.

Comment: Смысл определяет топикстартер, не? И если ему это зачем-то нужно, значит смысл есть. А уж маркетоидный бред про цены - это что вообще делает на *техническом* ресурсе? Если бы я хотел почитать за цены, то пошел бы на хабр

Comment: Да, стартапы и зарплаты - это вы тут сами придумали. Мой "стартап", который я делаю, по функциональности будет 20-ти летней давности, только бы он не жрат сотни мегабайт ресурсов. И нужда в нем появилась из-за "эффективных оптимизаторов зарплат" вроде вас, которые в погоне за стартапами делают так, что комьютерами 2-3 летней давности нельзя нормально пользоваться уже.

Comment: @bukkojot вы переоцениваете вклад разработчиков в целом (и оптимизаторов в частности) в успех любого стартапа.

Comment: Что есть успех? И зачем "стартап"? Если приложение невозможно запустить или с ним некомфортно работать из-за тормозов, то не будет ни стартапа, ни успеха, по крайней мере для меня.

Comment: @bukkojot повторю, если вы можете сформулировать четкие и однозначные факторы, **получится отличный вопрос**. Оптимизация в абстрактном виде не существует. Как минимум вам придется выбрать некоторую пропорцию между расходом памяти и временем выполнения.

Comment: Отлично, критерий вида "как можно меньшее использование памяти, пусть оно сжимает 10кб данных хоть 3 часа" - это устроит? Однако это может породить дискуссию.

Comment: @bukkojot устроит, почему нет-то? Дискуссии бывают разные. В плашке слово «дискуссия» означает холивар или бесконечный форумный трёп.

Comment: Для меня дискуссия != холивар. Опять кривой перевод?

Comment: @bukkojot кстати, зря вы меня в оптимизаторы зарплат записали, я инженер. Просто мне не заплатят за исследования ради искусства.

Comment: А программировать вы зачем начали? Не ради искусства? И если бы дворнику платили 100к, пошли бы в дворники?

Comment: Если совсем уж честно, то *начал* я программировать, чтобы выйти из депрессии и найти какой-то новый смысл в жизни. А сейчас стараюсь находить баланс между искусством и деньгами.

Comment: @bukkojot Успех - это если стартап прожил первые 3 года после запуска. Я вообще менеджер, а не программист. CTO, точнее.  Это не значит, что я не умею оптимизацию, просто я вынужден подходить к оценке вклада "оптимизации" с несколько другой точки зрения. И да, я программирую не ради искусства - программирование вообще никакого отношения к искусству не имеет. Просто решение сложных задач является одним из стандартных мотиваторов. Но на одном мотиваторе далеко не уедешь.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, но ведь с тем же результатом можно было бы вырезать фигурки из дерева или смотреть аниме. Вы просто решили "войти в ойти"? Без обид, но мне интереснее послушать человека, который программирует ради идеи, без коммерческого (шкурного) интереса, который начал изучать чистое программирование, использует его не как лекарство от душевной болезни, а как средство для изменения мира в лучшую сторону или создания своих миров, если этот мир изменить не получится.

Comment: @bukkojot самое интересное, что я программирую и вообще живу не для того, чтобы соответствовать вашим ожиданиям идеального собеседника. Если вам интереснее общаться с таким — пожалуйста, найдите и слушайте. Только не пишите мне больше ваших диагнозов и табличек на меня не вешайте, мне неприятно их читать.

Comment: @PashaPash, программирование - это именно искусство. А менеджеры, ставящие в приоритет шкурные интересы себя и компаний, не дающие проявить творчество, являются моими врагами. Именно из-за этих людей я вынужден пользоваться кривыми изделиями, которые выжирают сотни мегабайт памяти и могут подвесить всю машину, хотя вся их функциональность - отправить тег песенки или отобразить твит. Именно из-за этих людей я пишу привые программы, только бы быстрее отвязаться. Именно из-за них Линукс может похвастаться тем, что он сделан для людей, а не домохозяек.

Comment: @bukkojot Вот, видите - вот поэтому у нас вопросы об оптимизации без жестких критериев и запрещены. Потому что определенные пользователи просто не могут себя сдерживать, сразу вписывают других людей в список врагов и так далее. На самом деле кривые программы существуют *только* потому, что их кто-то пишет, пытаясь от кого-то "побыстрее отвязаться". и менеждеры тут ни при чем.

Comment: А зачем будет писать кривые программы, если ни от кого не надо будет убегать? Я мечтаю, что однажды программистам перестанут платить деньги вообще, это снова будет чистое искусство, а люди, которые работали ради денег - будут дворниками, таксистами или кем-то еще. Деньги - это единственное, что меня может смотивировать сделать что-то плохое, плохой код и обреченный проект в частности, в лучшем мире я бы просто за это не взялся, послав менеджера подальше.

Comment: Программирование может быть как искусством, так и ремеслом, причин, по которым появляются плохие программы тоже может быть множество, мир не является только лишь чёрно-белым. Вот что нехорошо -- так это нетерпимость к иным, не таким, как ты сам. Давайте что ли потихоньку свёрнем дискуссию, слишком далеко от вопроса ушли.

Comment: Ого, где вы видели зарплаты специалистов в 16k USD в месяц?

Comment: @avp это же просто пример. Но если считать реальную стоимость разработчика для работодателя, то она сильно выше зарплаты. 26% налогов сверху, офис, оборудование, зарплаты разного непроизводственного персонала от уборщиков до директора...

Comment: @NickVolynkin, и даже больше. Только с учетом всех налогов для того, чтобы заплатить работнику 16К, надо получить от покупателя его услуг 32К. И вы правы, к полученной сумме еще надо напродавать в 2 раза больше, чем сумма зарплат всего обслуживающего персонала (включая дирекцию с бухгалтерией) и плюс, чтобы хватило на аренду помещения, электричество и т.д. В результате  денег на зарплату собственно специалистам и не хватает...

Answer (score 6):

Часто вопросы по оптимизации являются либо

a) просто неумение разработчика пользователься профайлером. Тут, разумеется, будет ужасный вопрос вроде "Вот у меня репозиторий, программа жутко тормозит, спасайте…". Тут думаю без комментариев.

б) являются преждевременной оптимизацией (premature optimization).

Вообще преджевременная оптимизация приложений – очень опасная и глупая затея. Источник багов, трудноподдерживаемых программных конструкций и, как ни парадаксально это звучит, проблем со скоростью работы. Причём столкнулся с этим вживую, а не в статьях каких-нибудь крутых программистов. Это вовсе не значит, что код не стоит пытаться писать оптимально и не думать о том, как он будет работать. Просто фанатичность и недостаток профессионализма иногда играло злую шутку с некоторыми программистами.

---

Спрашивайте, когда вам реально важна скорость и желательно объясните почему текущая производительность вас может не устраивать (особенно, когда речь идёт о библиотечных методах). И обязательно прилагайте **результаты замеров** там, где вам нужна высокая производительность (по этой причине я считаю [пример вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/189730/) не совсем удачным, так как либо придётся наслово верить, что словари в .NET быстрей, чем в C++, либо брать и проверять). Может вам хочется заниматься "искусством" и оптимизировать ради удовольствия, я не против. Также далеко не во всех программах важна производительность. Уважайте время тех, кто ищет вполне практическую выгоду и конкретный результат в подобных вопросах.

Comment: Спасибо за более четкие чем у меня рекомендации.

Comment: Пример практической ценности от оптимизации: вы остались в середине дороги, телефон с GPS сел, вокруг на сотню километров есть около 50-ти местных жителей и дальнобойщики, которые не всегда останавливаются для помощи. А причиной было то, что для отрисовки трека была использована гламурная либа с антиалиасингом, альфаблендингом, плавными аниманиями на 60 fps, а UI был с красивыми гламурненькими анимированными кнопочками. И не нашлось никого, кто бы мог рассказать про технику Dirty Regions родом из 80х годов.

Comment: @bukkojot И? Я вот могу придумать пример когда человек может погибнуть из-за бага оптимизации. Не понимаю как вы пишите программы. Вы говорите заказчику, что будете писать простейшую программу полгода, так как "а вдруг она недостаточна оптимальна"? В чём посыл вашего примера? Оптимизация — наше всё?

Comment: @bukkojot И встречный вопрос: не сталкивались с проблемами преждевременной оптимизации? Что программа похожа на монстра и в ней добавились баги, так как кому-то показалась, что если программа будет работать на 2 микросекунды дольше, то это будет ужасно (и не факт, что этого удалось избежать)

Comment: Так получилось, что мой заказчик - это я сам. Человек, измученный отсутствием приемлемого софта. И задача ставится примерно так: написать хоть что-то рабочее, но не такое ужасное, как уже есть. Пусть это будет приложение состоящее из черного экрана с точкой по середине, лишь бы без рекламы, маркетинга и жора батарейки. Впрочем, такие требования я порой вижу и у реальных заказчиков, которым надоели из "кроссплатфонменные приложения на ионике", они тоже зачем-то хотят нейтива.

Comment: Да, с неработающими оптимизациями, или оптимизациями во вред, сталкиваюсь - не далее как вчера написал немного модифицированную версию алгоритма Хаффмана, получил не улучшение, а ухудшение сжатия. Так же узнал, что другие оптимизации по снижению энтропии дают незначительный прирост уровня компрессии. И даже если порой написать свой крутой алгоритм, оптимизированный под задачу - не факт, что он будет лучше, чем не оптимизированный под задачу, но реализованный на ассемблере.

Comment: Грустно мне становится от таких ответов. Хочется в очередной раз сказать -- *не нравится вопрос -- пройди мимо*.

Comment: @avp А что не так с ответом? Вопрос понравился, +1.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, я полагаю что avp имел ввиду, то что Вы ответили на частный случай в вопросе и не затронули общую тему уместности дискусий на SO и изменение плашки предостерегающей о возможных холиварах.

Comment: @bukkojot , хотел у Вас узнать, какая связь между оптимизацией и исскуством? Как правило оптимизированный код теряет на порядки в красоте и читаемости и стремлением к прекрасному я не могу объяснить необходимость оптимизации. Это именно необходимость продиктованная требованиями, отсюда и ограничения на указание конкретных критериев.

Comment: @bukkojot , опять же оптимизация это чаще всего палка о двух концах. И у каждой оптимизации есть обратная сторона медали. Оптимизируя к примеру потребляемую память, мы как правило больше кушаем процессор и наоборот. Отсюда опять же требование к указанию конкретных критериев для оптимизации. Это качели! серебрянной пули не существует. И я думаю Вы будете крайне недовольны приложением, которое ест мало процессорного времени, и как следствие ест меньше батареи, но при этом хранит гигабайты кеша и нарезанные на любые случаи превью Ваших фото. Важен баланс.

Answer (score 2):

Такие рассуждения о дискуссии приятны, но это в "теории", "на практике" все как всегда по другому. Появляется спор, рано или поздно перерастающий в "священные войны". Даже твой вопрос является таковым и ответа ты так и не нашел. Люди так устроенны, они просто ищут подтверждения своей догадки. В дискуссии рождается компромисс, в споре - перетягивание одеяла, рождается посредственность, рождается инструмент. Вот почему людям приятнее писать на Haskell - он просто такой какой есть, в С++ - стандарт и компромиссы, которые тоже рождают холивары.

Очень интересно мнение Марка Лутца по этому поводу. Программирование - ремесло, т.к когда программист делает программу, он делает что то, что будет улучшатся и использоваться другими людьми. А ведь художник не рассчитывает на то что его картину дорисуют. Я считаю, в его руках появляется его произведение, а программы - это продукт, бизнес. С++ - не зло, т.к и Джава. Дискуссии бывают продуктивными только в стенах ANSI или ISO. Здесь же, просто спор с перетягиванием одеяла.

Comment: Я мечтаю, что однажды, для всех тех, для кого "программирование - это бизнес" - оно им быть перестанет. Эти люди найдут себя в качестве дворника или уборщика. И я снова буду программировать, не подгоняемый эффективными менеджерами и не оглядываясь на какую-то там стоимость.

Comment: Вот почему я люблю программирование. Мне приятно что у меня есть единомышленники. Бизнес - зло, но если его не будет, не будет и приятно от того что ты не зависишь от менеджера. Вот почему я хочу выучить Лисп, и разрабатывать свои продукты на нем. Сейчас. Если не будет зла, то как ты поймешь что добро - это добро?