# Платят ли тем кто здесь давно активит, в чём ваш смысл?

Tags: обсуждение

Всегда задумывался о идеи StackOverflow, со взгляда того кто хочет сделать свой проект. Никогда бы не подумал что сайт для программистов, которых и так мало, в сравнении допустим с геймерами, киноманами, и т.д. будет такой популярный, к тому же с такой активной аудиторией. Люди здесь сидят взрослые как я понял, и неужели это чистое желание, помогать с ответами, а они не краткие, и не глупые, когда вы к тому же ещё занятой по идее специалист, у которого своя взрослая жизнь? Если вопрос глупый и не уместный, то я могу удалить его, только скажите)

**Update: Почему этот вопрос не связан с -** [Зачем вы здесь?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C) ? Потому что там обсуждается смысл время проведения тех кто постоянно сидит на этом сайте, и поднимается вопрос зачем они это делают.

А я лишь хотел поделится мыслью, что будучи в поисках идеи, к примеру, я бы никогда не подумал бы что этот проект будет таким успешным, и уж точно не подумал бы что он наберет такую популярность и аудиторию + войдет в топ 20 сайтов по данным https://alexa.com

Почему я так считаю? Формула проста

> 1.Программистов мало это первое, и большинство из них сидят на рабочих местах, и не у всех есть время задавать, и тем более отвечать на
> вопросы
>
> 2.Многие из них взрослые и  занятые люди, которые не станут как школьники сидеть на форумах, к тому же работа + личная жизнь, когда
> ещё?
>
> 3.Ответы это готовый код, который не каждый захочет составлять просто так, тратя на это время, ради какой-то репутации

В итоге получаем что? Никто бы не поверил в этот проект, а если бы и поверил, то сказал бы, большой посещаемости не жди

То есть можно сказать я восхищен грандиозным успехом сообщества SO, и думая о этой идее как о плане построения проекта, я был бы более чем уверен что она провалилась бы

Просто я юнец который со школьного возраста промышляет собственными сайтами, ну и имя собственный опыт + основанную на этом логику, благодаря примеру SO, я понял что всё возможно, и ничего никогда нельзя  всё полностью просчитать, и говорить о том что будет наверняка

Comment: Тоже задавался этим вопросом) прогеров мало, тех кто сидит на форумах ещё меньше, учитывая то что взрослая жизнь, работа, семья все дела, да и код нужно писать - но нет, сайт входит в топ alexa.com

Comment: не платят. совсем.

Comment: Всё просто — каждый разбирается в своей относительно узкой области. Поэтому сегодня вы отвечающий, завтра пассивный читатель чужих вопросов-ответов, а послезавтра уже вопрошающий. И это нормально, на этом сайт и держится.

Comment: Очевидно, что у каждого свои причины. Раньше было интересно профессионально пообщаться в комментариях (по сути дела, вопрос и ответы были затравкой для трепа). Сейчас этого уже почти нет (новый контингент довольно строго следует установленным свыше правилам).

Comment: Программист с опытом большую часть времени не пишет, а думает над решением и архитектурой. Программистов мало и порой даже нет коллег, которым можно задать срочный вопрос. А если и есть, то не факт, что они знают ответ. Каждый программист рано или поздно сталкивается со сложной задачей, идет в интернет и перебирает кучу информации. И чем сложнее вопрос, тем больше шансов вообще ничего не найти. Поэтому специалисты вынуждены искать друг друга для обмена опытом. Как правильно говорят - возьмите группу людей и узнайте, с какими действительно проблемами они сталкиваются и потом дайте им решение.

Comment: К тому же все рабочие часы что-то писать так себе идея. На реальных примерах можно заметить, что с таким подходом люди больше всего устают, теряют эффективность и зарабатывают нервные срывы и хандру. Если это не дедлайн (или не стажировка новичка), я думаю тут большинство делает перерывы или имеют пару часиков, в которых сидят на других сайтах во время кратковременных перерывов и заходят на SO.

Comment: А что, платят таки? А я не знал (_хнык_)

Comment: _Все три приведённых тезиса "несостоятельности идеи SO" неверны, как минимум из этого неверен вывод._ **1.** Программистов немало. Учитывайте тех, для кого это не является основной работой. Но и не стоит предполагать, что такие программисты чем-то хуже. **2.** SO не форум, здесь на единицу времени можно принести куда больше пользы большому числу людей. **3.** Нет, ответы не всегда готовый код. А ответ только из готового кода, как правило, плох и достоин минуса. Вопрос, прямо требующий готовый код, тоже рискует отхватить минусов.

Comment: @D-side не перестает удивлять безапеляционность подобных утверждений... `2. SO не форум, здесь на единицу времени можно принести куда больше пользы большому числу людей`. Отличий SO от форума не столь много, чтобы раз за разом обращать на это внимание.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper достаточно отличий вытекает уже из другой решаемой задачи: обсуждение против сбора и концентрации знаний. Здесь обсуждения не приветствуются (против определения форума, который для них создан), зато править можно любые сообщения (вопросы и ответы), даже чужие (это для форумов просто нонсенс, т. к. сообщения тесно привязаны к авторам). Да, попадаются форумы, на которых модераторы активно охотятся за темами-дублями и добавляют в "шапку" информацию от всех желающих, но это костыль, отходящий от формата форумов в целом. В SE же это является практически основанием.

Comment: @D-side не приветствуются обсуждения? вижу обратное. `зато править можно любые сообщения (вопросы и ответы), даже чужие (это для форумов просто нонсенс, т. к. сообщения тесно привязаны к авторам).`  тут согласен - огромный шаг вперед, но вопрошающим абсолютно все равно кем будет редактироваться их ответ. Они задают вопросы с конкретной целью - получить ответ. Качество и скорость получения оного зависит лишь от популярности ресурса.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper [да, не приветствуются](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5484/181100). Цель же вопрошающих -- движущая сила, позволяющая ресурсу существовать. Средство для достижения SO поставленных задач, но не самоцель.

Comment: @D-side забавно что участник задавший вопрос оказался заблокированным ;-) Обсуждение видел и даже голосовал. Возвращаясь к теме -  даже на форумах люди предпочитают в профильных разделах вопросы, на которые можно дать конкретные ответы. Для холиваров и разговоров за жизнь обычно существуют специальные разделы.

Comment: Как периодически всплывающий тут - ничего не меняется. Для профессионала полезной информации ноль. Вспомнить базовые вещи и отточить мелочи - да, это очень полезно на самом деле. Спасибо за это. Идея [ru]SO как концентратора знаний - да не смешите...