# Ответ или не ответ?

Tags: обсуждение

Возникло непонимание участников, отклонивших тревогу по [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/793886/191745) на данный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/793822/191745):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На мой взгляд это выглядит так, как если бы человек обратился на вокзал:

-- Господа, возможно ли как-то добраться до Петербурга?

-- Сударь сейчас зима и трудно добраться, купите лошадь.

Т.е. в принципе есть что-то похожее на ответ (ни да ни нет) и совет, но что дальше делать и в какую сторону <strike>скакать</strike> непонятно.
Из ответа получается, что вроде бы можно сделать, но как не говорится, можно пойти другой дорогой, но как (?) тоже не говорится (без переходов по другим сайтам).

Да, была ссылка на решение на другом сайте (правда решение не совпадало с текстом ответа), но по сути это ответ-ссылка и с большей степенью вероятности данный ответ был бы удален через очередь проверки. Кроме этого ссылка могла оказаться недоступной со временем или именно в то время когда кто-то зашел на страницу вопроса с такой же проблемой.

Вопрос в том, почему это является ответом ? Какие насчет этого мнения?

---

*Данный вопрос не возник бы, если можно было бы увидеть реакцию тех, кто отклонил тревогу, например комментарий автору ответа с пояснением, что не так в ответе, но ее нет. Поэтому хотелось бы понять тех, кто отклонил тревогу.*

Comment: тревогу отклонили обычные участники, а не модератор: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/241574. бывает.

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо, не знал, "на заборе" написано модератор :)

Answer (score 3):

-- Как забить гвоздь отвёрткой?

-- Но постойте, возьмите лучше молоток.

Для меня этот ответ выглядит таким образом. В целом, ответ, как ответ. Полезный он или нет, решит уже сам автор вопроса.

> Вопрос в том, почему это является ответом ? Какие насчет этого мнения?

С другой стороны, почему это не является ответом?

Comment: Если Вы не знаете, как забить гвоздь с помощью молотка, Вы будете искать информацию об этом. Аналогично, для получения конкретного ответа Вам нужно искать гораздо больше информации, и такой ответ практически ничем не поможет участникам с подобной проблемой. На мой взгляд, указанный ответ в первоначальном виде есть хороший и полезный комментарий, но не более.

Answer (score 1):

> Вопрос в том, почему это является ответом ? Какие насчет этого мнения?

В моей интерпретации этого ответа ответ там прячется между строк — **никак**. И объясняется, почему. И предлагается альтернативный подход.

То есть, непосредственно текст ответа содержит только дополнения к ответу, а сам ответ содержит только между строк — он заключается в **причине** того, почему эти детали вообще нужны/полезны.

Не знаю, почему автор не объявил ответ прямо.

- Возможно, не уверен в нём.
- Возможно, просто не думал о прямоте ответа.
- Возможно, знает прямое решение (если оно вообще существует), но оно не стоит того.

Этому ответу не помешала бы правка, но удалению он точно не подлежит.

Comment: в том, то и дело) ответ *никак* - это все же ответ. *очень плохо поддается стилизации* звучит, что можно, но трудно, следовательно назревает вопрос *пусть трудно, но как?*. Далее в  ответе было дано альтернативное направление со ссылкой в которой реализация отличалась от предложенной в ответе. В итоге - точного ответа нет, есть ссылка на сторонний сайт по которой информация по реализации отличается от предложения. Может показаться, что это придирка, но как же *вопрос-ответ, ничего лишнего* ?

Comment: @Alex совершенно верно, "никак" это **тоже ответ**. "Ничего лишнего" относится больше к [дискуссиям](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5488/181100), чтобы читатели со стороны сразу видели полезную информацию, а не километры комментариев. Дополнения в ответах вовсе не лишние.

Comment: Я исхожу из следующей логики: допустим Вы не знаете css совсем. **1.** Вы видите ответ *очень плохо поддается стилизации*. Не возникнет ли у Вас вопроса (допустим только для собственного развития) *если трудно, то можно, но как ?* Вы пишите автору ответа, а обратной связи от него нет. Это первый минус.

Comment: **2.** С камнем в душе, что ответа не 1 вопрос нет, Вы читаете *... div вместо select и span вместо option* и видите ссылку. Ок, супер, хоть что-то... Однако: **2.1** - ссылка может не работать, **2.2** по ссылке какие-то `input`, `label`, а в ответе рекомендуют `span` и `div` - *автор ответа имел крутое решение, но ошибся ссылкой* ? вроде бы подходит, но странно... Вот такая странная логика. И что-то мне подсказывает, что данный ответ был бы удален в ходе проверки через очередь.

Comment: @Alex это означает только то, что ответ **плохой**. И, возможно, заслуживает минус. Но он пытается ответить на вопрос. Он не обсуждает вопрос перпендикулярно его решению, не задаёт автору вопросов, не высказывает своё желание получить ответ на этот же вопрос.

Comment: однако соглашусь, что с определенной стороны это все же ответ, пусть и ответ-ссылка, только лично на мой взгляд это больше похоже на комментарий и в первоначальном виде толку в комментариях от него было бы больше.