# Почему, на ваш взгляд, в чате ruSO так мало новых лиц?

Tags: обсуждение, чат

Собственно сам вопрос и подвопросы к нему:

1. Почему, на ваш взгляд, в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) ruSO так мало новых лиц?
2. Насколько полезно сообществу ruSO иметь деятельных собеседников в нём?
3. Что может испугать "новичков" вступить в общение там?
4. Знают ли возможные пользователи чата о его существовании?
5. Каким образом их можно было бы туда привлечь (если ответ на 2-й вопрос для вас имеет больше преимуществ, чем недостатков)?

Хотелось бы узнать мнение деятельных пользователей Meta ruSO на этот счёт.

Comment: SE не особо приветствует общение в чате и комментариях, т.к. ориентация больше на накопление формализованных знаний именно на сайте. Поэтому, в сущности, особых шагов на популяризацию чата никто не делает.

Comment: А вообще, уже было такое обсуждение: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3983/15479. С тех пор в этом плане ничего не поменялось.

Comment: @Suvitruf в приведённой ссылке не нашёл ответов на свои вопросы. А по поводу "не особо приветствует" было бы познавательно почитать

Comment: @edem, а вот это, хороший, правильный вопрос. Только вы считаете, что контингент Меты сильно отличается от контингента дискуссий у Генерала?

Comment: @edem вряд ли вы найдёте пост официальный, где явно бы говорилось что-то такое. Но можете поискать сообщения Николая в чате или на мете, где он писал про это. Во-вторых, можно почитать треды на MSE вроде [этого](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309645/260198) или [этого](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270599/260198). SE годами ничего не делает с чатом, никакое из предложений по улучшению не было реализовано. Чат не в приоритете, просто второстепенный не особо важный функционал.

Comment: @edem прекратите. У нас везде на сайте и в интерфейсе чат называется чатом. И люди, которые будут искать похожие вопросы, будут искать именно по этому ключевому слову.

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: @Suvitruf действую по вашим советам: вот https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=51875639#51875639 и вот https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=51875483#51875483

Comment: @defaultlocale https://ru.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8&title=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%3A%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA&go=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8&ns0=1 вот пример, чего нет, нельзя использовать? Или вот, тоже против https://ru.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%81&title=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%3A%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA&go=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8&ns0=1.

Comment: @Suvitruf ну вот считайте я буду первым называть (переводить) chat как беседка и искать буду по слову беседка. Для поиска оставлю метку, какую вы предложили, остальное, пожалуйста, не трогайте.

Comment: @edem заголовок я поменяю, всё же.

Comment: @Suvitruf с дополнением если только.

Comment: @edem Я не в том смысле что слово нельзя использовать, это личное дело каждого. Просто я никогда не слышал чтобы чат называли беседкой и у «беседки» есть другие, более распространенные, значения. Меня это слово сбило с толку, думаю я не один такой. С другой стороны «чат» — слово , которое используется в ссылках и комментариях и значение которого понятно абсолютно всем. Если Вы хотели его локализовать (*pardon*, отместничить), то получилось, имхо, не очень. Все равно что телефон называть долгозвуком, никто не поймет.

Comment: На сайте нет беседки. Сайт - не дача. Есть чат. Ваши попытки навязать некий "чистый русский язык", без иностранных слов лично я считаю оскорбительными, а правки и откат исправлений "чат" на "беседка" - вандализмом. Жду, пока модераторы примут меры, т.к. imho, это зашло слишком далеко.

Comment: @defaultlocale да просто человеку не нравятся английские слова, он считает их использование нарушением некой "чистоты языка" и пытается пропихнуть "беседка" вместо "чат", "пропуск" вместо "пароль" и "обзорщик" вместо "браузер". *не понимаю, почему модераторы до сих пор это не пресекли.* :(

Comment: @PashaPash - `"обзорщик" вместо "браузер"` - *интернет-обозреватель*.

Comment: @edem, всё-таки чат придётся называть "чатом", потому что это абсолютно новое понятие, для которого нет аналогий среди того, что уже названо словами русского языка. "Беседка" - это строение (малая архитектурная форма, если угодно), так что "беседка" не равно "место для бесед".

Comment: Не спорю, что использование иностранного слова при наличии уже имеющейся полноценной замены в русском языке - это откровенное замусоривание. Но для новых вещей и понятий, увы, приходится заимствовать и новые слова. Например, предметы быта в тюркских и французском языках, технические понятия в немецком, абстрактные понятия в греческом, общественные понятия в латыни.

Comment: @defaultlocale, `Вы хотели его локализовать (pardon, отместничить)` — а разве "перевести" не включает в себя изменение-адаптацию оригинала под культурные особенности читателей перевода?

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev "веб-браузер" практически вытеснил "интернет-обозреватель" -  Chrome, Edge, Mozilla, даже Yandex - используют или "браузер" или "веб-браузер" на своих официальных русских страницах.

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev Тут нюанс :) Хотелось отделить ситуацию, в которой английское слово переводится на русский, от ситуации, в которой русское слово с английскими корнями заменяется на новое слово со славянскими корнями. Не уверен что «локализовать» лучшее слово в этом контексте, но полагаю что читатели поймут. В другом контексте «перевести» подошло бы, спасибо!

Comment: @PashaPash зачем вы исправили остальные слова в самом вопросе (помимо меток и заголовка для поиска)? А как же ваше "я не вижу никаких причин запрещать другим людям активно участвовать в словообразовании."

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev в русском языке полно примеров, когда уже существующими понятиями обозначают новые для нашей отрасли: рабочий стол, стена, лента, ярлык и т.п.

Comment: @edem я заменил "остальные слова" на существующие общеупотребимые русскоязычные термины. Если вы недовольны тем, что другие пользователи улучшают ваши сообщения - почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/editing.

Comment: @PashaPash в беседке вы на эти ссылки не ссылались при личном общении. Понял. Это было ваше личное мнение. Учту на будущее.

Answer (score -1):

> 1. Почему, на ваш взгляд, в чате ruSO так мало новых лиц?

Не исключаю возможности того, что "новые лица" всё-таки заходят в беседку, но по каким-либо своим причинам там не задерживаются надолго. Из-за этого их как бы и нет вовсе: зашёл, оглянулся, ухмыльнулся и повернулся назад.

> 2. Насколько полезно сообществу ruSO иметь деятельных собеседников в нём?

Насчёт пользы. Для создателей SO беседка (англ. chat) не приносит просмотров, на которых можно было бы заработать с помощью рекламы. Таким образом это скорее служебное орудие, призванное поддерживать основную работу SO, а не заменять его.

> 4. Знают ли возможные пользователи чата о его существовании?

На основном сайте об этом можно узнать лишь наткнувшись на ссылку в комментариях, где предлагают продолжить беседу в беседке (чате). Либо справа на Meta. Таким образом скорее нет, чем да. Ибо даже если встретят ссылку-призывалку в беседку, то скорее всего воспримут её как ЛС (личные сообщения), а не полноценную беседу среди нескольких участников.

Comment: Они бы могли в чат рекламу добавить. Так что, невалидный первый поинт.

Comment: Не совсем понял последнее "слово", но добавить то может быть и могли, только вот из поисковиков туда особо не попасть, поэтому просмотров особо не видать (ну в текущем виде, по крайней мере).

Comment: Со мной так и было: совершенно случайно наткнулся на ссылку, посмотрел оглянулся и ушел. Сейчас периодически захожу, колесом покручу и ухожу.